# data binding error when I try set params with @BindingAdapter

Tags: android

I want to set custom font to my TextView with @BindingAdapter annotation.

This is my class:

```
public class DataBindingAdapters {
    @BindingAdapter("boldHebrewText")
    public static void boldCusomText(@NonNull TextView tv, @NonNull String text) {
        tv.setText(text);
        FontUtils.setFont(tv, FontUtils.OPEN_SANS_BOLD);
    }
}
```

And this part from my xml:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        style="@style/JWidget.EditText.White"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:boldHebrewText="@{Name}"... />
```

And when I try to build apk I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. Name is missing it
>   file:C:\android\work\Projects\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_sign_in.xml
>   loc:67:34 - 67:37
>   ****\ data binding error ****

**How to fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app:boldHebrewText="@{Name}"`, `Name` must be a variable declared in data tags, eg,

```
<data>
  <variable name="Name" type="java.lang.String" />
</data>
```

Or `Name` not being a variable, but String value, so

```
app:boldHebrewText="@{`Name`}"
```